# VB.NET Data type mismatch, and data entry is to long

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, oledb

I have been working on this for days now, and any help would be great. I am trying to insert information into database using VB.NET and an access database. Currently I am having 2 problems with it. The first problem is that I have a memo field in my database (Response), and if I try to insert more than 250 characters into that field I get an error that says my entry is to long. The other problem I am having is that if I try to execute this code more than once while running my program I get an error saying "Data type mismatch in criteria expression...". The last issue is the one I am having with the data type mismatch.

here is the code in question

```
    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=..\..\Backends\IncidentReport.mdb")
    con.Open()
    comStr = "INSERT INTO tblIncidentCommonItemsInfo(recid, Location, DescOrTypeInjIfOther, DateOf, TimeOf, TypeIncident, Doctor, " &
            "DateDocNotified, TimeDocNotified, DateRespPartyNotified, RespPartyNotified, " &
            " TimeRespPartyNotified, StateNotified, DateStateNotified, TimeStateNotified, Response) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(comStr, con)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", IDLabel.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", LocTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", DescTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", DateOfTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", TimeOfTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", TypeTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", DocComboBox.SelectedItem)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", DocDayDateTimePicker.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", DocTimeDateTimePicker.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", FamilyDayDateTimePicker.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", RespPtyTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p12", FamilyTimeDateTimePicker.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p13", IDPHYesNoComboBox.SelectedItem)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p14", IDPHDayDateTimePicker.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p15", IDPHTimeDateTimePicker.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p16", ResidentWordsRichTextBox.Text)

        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Incident Saved")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " - " & ex.Source)
        End Try
        SavedTextBox.Text = "Yes"
        con.Close()
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the size problem you could try to specify exactly what kind of value you are passing through the parameter. I suspect that using AddWithValue will use a shorter parameter size

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p16", OleDbType.LongVarWChar).Value = ResidentWordsRichTextBox.Text)
```

The `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` error could be caused by the same problem.
The method AddWithValue determines the Parameter DataType looking at the type of the value you pass.

In your code you have passed Text for fields that appear to be of different kind. For example `recid` seems to be an integer (numeric) field, but the AddWithValue use a textbox.text that is a string. You really should apply a `Convert.ToInt32(IDLabel.Text)` and the same checking should be done for the potetially DateTime fields

Comment: I still get this error:    The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add.  Try inserting or pasting less data.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. It works as expected. If it is not a problem you could send me the database with your sample table and I will try to test on your schema

Comment: Could you not reproduce either problem or just the mismatch problem

Comment: I have tried just the size problem. Using an Access 2003 with Jet.4.0 and ACE.12.0 for Access2010. But the Memo field receives correctly the data loaded from a file of 140K without a fuss. (64bit win7)